# Several invalid numpy distributions

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I have several warnings for invalid numpy distributions when running `pip list` and always get `import "numpy/numba" could not be resolved` errors in VS Code. I tried handling numpy separately in a conda venv, however, it fails to build a wheel for numpy, even when I purged the pip cache and tried installing numpy with `pip install --no-cache-dir numpy==1.19.1`.

I require a specific version of numpy, i.e, (numpy==1.19.1) as I'm using a specific version of numba for a project, but I just can't seem to resolve the issue.

Could anyone point me in the direction of how to resolve this?

I'm on Mac OS (Mojave 10.14.6) with Python 3.8.10.

Comment: Have you tried creating new environment? This sometimes help and is cheap to try.

Comment: Yes, after some meddling around it worked! Thanks! I also got the directory up on Google Colab and was able to handle package distributions really easily there as well.